# Sort a List of File

Tags: java, file, for-loop, arraylist, directory

How can I list the files of multiple directorys in Java?

That's what I've tried:

```
ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
for(int x = 0; x < directorys.length; x++) {
    if(directorys[x].isDirectory()) {
        files.addAll(Arrays.asList(directorys[x].listFiles(filter)));
    } 
}
```

That works kind of, but the problem is, that it doesn't bring the files into a fully alphabetic order.
It's than sth. like this: *(first folder) 1, 3, 5, (second folder) 2, 4, 6*. But I'd like it to be like this: *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6*.
So I guess, what it does, is that it brings all the files of each folder into the correct order, but not all files together.
How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort using a comparator:

```
files.sort((a,b)-> a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list of files after the loop like below

```
files.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::getName));
```